# before filter not skipping on signup page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a before filter that is supposed to stand down on the signup page (/signup) but it is still redirecting to login.

How do I fix this to leave out the signup page, which is my create/new action.

right now this is in my `application_contorller.rb`

```
before_filter :require_login
  skip_before_filter :require_login, :except => [:create,:new,:accept]

private

  def require_login
    unless current_user
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
before_filter :require_login, :except => [:create, :new, :accept]
```

Alternatively, you can specify the pages that require login like this:

```
before_filter :require_login, :only => [:delete, :index, :another_controller_action_that_requires_login, :etc]
```

You'll likely want to move this before_filter to `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` (or whatever controller is responsible for user sign ups) instead of leaving it in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`.

If you leave the `:before_filter` in application controller and have another `:new` or `:create` action in a separate controller (`contact_form_controller.rb` for example) then the before_filter will apply to that as well if it inherits from `ApplicationController`.

Comment: so I tried the first one and it just allows all the pages without a login. so weird.

Comment: it should work - see edit regarding moving this filter from ApplicationController to UsersController (or whatever controller is related to sign ups).